# CSS Jquery - Active Link

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can anyone see what i am doing wrong here? Trying to get an active state working and i really cant see what i have done wrong here.

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    //<![CDATA[
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('#nav li').each(function() {
            var href = jQuery(this).find('a').attr('href');
            if (href === window.location.pathname) {
                jQuery(this).addClass('current');
            }
        });
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#Link1">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Link2">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Link3">Link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Link4">Link4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Link5">Link5</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
    #nav li.current a { color: red;}
    #nav li.current { background-color: red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
if (href === window.location.href) {
```

instead of

```
if (href === window.location.pathname) {
```

Comment: Still not working. Ive tried with IE9 and Chrome. Using the latest jquery which i have included. jquery-1.11.1.min.js

Comment: @user263029 You might want to check if your `window.location.href` contains your `.attr('href')` rather than `===`.

Comment: Hm, try to add console.log(href, window.location.href), and see what are you compering and use  == instead off === to compare

Comment: Just click of any of your links and check if address is changing in address bar. Of course not as those link linking to your elements on same page so window.location.pathname is not going to work

Comment: Got it working with this

              <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
             $(window).load(function(){
              $("li").click(function() {
    $("li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
          });
           });//]]>  

             </script>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the active state with anchor links (as seen in your specific question) then it won't work with `window.location.pathname` because it only gives pathname after the domain name and not the anchor link within the page. You will have to use `window.location.href`, but even that gives the  whole link while you will only get the part after # from your `href` attribute. I would use [string.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match). So it would look something like this

```
//Matching if href ever occurs in windows.location.href
if (window.location.href.match(href)){
//do something
}
```

Also because match actually takes a regex (it actually returns the matching strings or null if no match) you can be more specific by add a $ at the end(used for checking end of string) to see whether the link end with this anchor link or not.